# Numeric Textbox-Custom Control Validator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am creating a numeric textbox control that validates the following:

- Only Numbers are allowed
- If an input is greater than 50 shows a message and
- the input length no greater than 2 numbers.

My code below checks that only numbers are allowed however I am struggling to develop the other 2 conditions.  Thanks in advance

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress( KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ignore all non-control and non-numeric key presses.
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Only Numbers are allowed");
        }else if (e.KeyChar > '6')
        {
            MessageBox.Show("greater than 50");

        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `NumericUpDown` control.

Answer (score 0):

The KeyPress-Event provides only the last pressed character. To validate the whole input you need to combine the current Text and the pressed character.

```
string combText = this.Text + e.KeyChar;
```

The resulting string can then be validated:

1. Try to parse it to int

   int.TryParse(combText, out int res);
2. Check if the result is greater than 50

   res > 50
3. Check if the lenght of the input greater than 2

   combText.Length > 2

In your code:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //combine the current Text and the pressed KeyChar;
    string combText = this.Text + e.KeyChar;
    if (combText.Length > 2 && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        //prevent the input lenght to be greater than 2
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    // Ignore all non-control and non-numeric key presses.
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Only Numbers are allowed");
    }
    else if (int.TryParse(combText, out int res) && res > 50)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("greater than 50");
    }

    base.OnKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: the answer indeed checks that the input is greater than 50 however what I need is that the checkbox stop the user from entering more than two numbers. Still great answer! Thank you

Comment: @fernandonicolalde i edited my answer to fulfill your requirements. let me know if you still have problems with it

Comment: Yes indeed the answer now stop the user to enter more than 2 numbers but now I cannot edit the input entered. Delete key does not work

Comment: any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You need to check for control Keys like you already did in the numbers only part: !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)